# Releasing from Nexus staging repository via Jenkins/Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have a Java project.  Some parts are `jar` files, some are `war` files.  I also have Jenkins and Nexus Pro, whereby when a developer on the team commits to SVN, the Jenkins build automatically kicks off.

Using the Maven versions plugin, I am able to `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.$SVN_REVISION` as a pre-build step, and then `mvn clean test deploy`.  At the end of this process, I've got a `my-artifact-1.0.1234.jar` uploaded to my Nexus Pro Staging Repository.

Since we're working in a CI-type of environment, we might have a hundred (or more) staging builds.  When the time is right, the QA team wants to promote a certain build to a "later" environment (think QA, or SIT, or whatever.  Environments are more of a locked-down state here.)

The workflow that I want to have happen is this:

1. Someone decides that Build 1.0.1357 should be Promoted to QA
2. They go into Jenkins, go to the "Promote to QA" job
3. They're presented with a list of all possible builds in the Nexus Staging Repository in a drop-down.  They select one, and click the "Run" button.
4. That artifact is "released" from Nexus Staging to Nexus Releases, and further deployed to the QA environment.  (I'm not as concerned about the "and deployed to QA" part -- I know how to do that already.  It's included here for completeness-of-my-story sake.)

I already know that I can do this from the command-line, and it's working:

```
mvn nexus-staging:rc-list -DserverId=nexus -DnexusUrl=http://my.nexus.ip:8081/nexus
mvn nexus-staging:rc-release -DserverId=nexus -DnexusUrl=http://my.nexus.ip:8081/nexus -DstagingRepositoryId=abcd-1000 -Ddescription="Release from CLI."
```

The problem I'm having is that you have to specify the `stagingRepositoryId` on the command-line.  How might I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Just to note: I don't want to use SNAPSHOTs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I was doing is parsing the output of

```
mvn nexus-staging:rc-list -DserverId=nexus -DnexusUrl=http://my.nexus.ip:8081/nexus
```

and then just match the needed repository with your specifique logic. Using python for me was the best solution (but you can do it on your own with any language):

```
output = subprocess.check_output("mvn nexus-staging:rc-list -DserverId=nexus -DnexusUrl=http://my.nexus.ip:8081/nexus")

for line in output.split('\n'):
    if "repo" in line:
        stagingRepositoryId = "repo-" + line[8:23]
```

Considering output as

```
[INFO] repo_qa-3514 OPEN     Implicitly created (auto staging).
[INFO] repo_qa-3518     Implicitly created (auto staging).
[INFO] repo_qa-3521 OPEN     Implicitly created (auto staging).
[INFO] repo-2011     OPEN     Implicitly created (auto staging).
```

You will run the second command after parsing as:

```
mvn nexus-staging:rc-release -DserverId=nexus -DnexusUrl=http://my.nexus.ip:8081/nexus -DstagingRepositoryId=repo-2011 -Ddescription="Release from CLI."
```

Comment: I re-worked this answer to use a "Groovy System Script" inside the Extensible Choice Parameter (from the Extensible Choice Plugin) to get me the drop-down that I wanted, and promote my Staging Repository to Releases.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved readily by using SNAPSHOT and release repository.
So you do your normal development in a SNAPSHOT build and once you are ready for testing, you can create a tag build which removes SNAPSHOT from version in POM. All this can be achieved using jenkins and Nexus.

Also you dont need SVN revision number in your version, instead an incremental build number will be sufficient which can be managed via release plugin.

So to summarise:

1. Lets say you are working on release 1.0.
2. So you take a initial branch with pom version as 1.0-0-SNAPSHOT . Here 1.0 represents release number, '-0' represents next tag build number which we plan to deploy.
3. Now once you are ready for deployment or want your QA team to test. You run a job or a script with maven release plugin to create a tag. A tag build will be created with version 1.0-0 [Snapshot is removed so it will go to release repository] and uploaded to repository also version in branch will be incremented to 1.0-1-SNAPSHOT [So now changes in branch will be made to release and deploy 1.0-1 if any changes are needed]

All the above steps are automated using Maven release plugin and run via jenkins job.

I have the above setup for my work.

---

OP stated that 'SNAPSHOT' is not in picture. 
In that case this post answers the query : [automate deployment to sonatype's oss maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902873/automate-deployment-to-sonatypes-oss-maven-repository)  [Look at the second answer]

Comment: I didn't mention SNAPSHOTs because I don't want to use them.  I want to use a Nexus Staging repository, and promote numbered builds to the Releases repository.